# Plotting xy data in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, arcmap, point, xy

I have a .csv containing the name, longitude, and latitude in the first, second and third column, respectively. Longitude and latitude are in decimal degrees in WGS 84. However, if I try to plot these on a Plate Carree basemap, they all show up at at the intersection of the 0 meridian and the equator. I've tried some other projection but no luck so far.

I need to convert the data to a shapefile to use in a different software afterward.

Comment: Have you set your projection in the map properties prior to bringing in a file? This may cause a mismatch. Also, check that the Lat and Long fields are not swapped around, as sadly I have seen this before in files.

Comment: How did you added the CSV in ArcMap, and how was the projection applied?

Comment: "WGS 84" is not a projection. It is the basis for dozens to hundreds of projections. You have most likely chosen an incorrect one.  Please [Edit] the Question to specify your exact steps and choices.